# ngu-carousel :: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I am referring to this example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngu-carousel-ng6?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

But in console, I am getting this error

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has
>   changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngForOf: '. Current
>   value: 'ngForOf: 0,1,2,3,4,5'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/sheikalthaf/ngu-carousel/issues/83) is the workaround for your problem

You can use **ChangeDetectionStrategy**

like,

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
```